# How to write a function that accepts a number as an argument and prints each number from 1 up to that maximum and boxed by square brackets?

Tags: python

I don't know how to include square brackets to box the outcomes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn7mf.jpg)

Comment: You should read [ask]. As StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service, to get help you should make an honest attempt to solve this yourself, then include your code in your question as a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

How about any of the following:

```
print("[{}]".format(number))
print("[%d]" % number)
print([number])
print("["+str(number)+"]")
print("[", number, "]")
```

Answer (score -2):

def printNumber(num:int):
#printing the numbers in a single line
for i in range(1,num+1):
print('[%d]'%i, end = ")

if **name** == '**main**':
#test code
printNumber(15)

Comment: You might want to add formatting to your code sample